# RabbitMq losing messages with no connections

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have recently setup rabbitMq.

I'm unfamiliar with alot of the ampq terminology so I may be missing something simple.

#### My Scenario

I have a queue that i've published messages to, and connected and disconnected some consumers or clients.

Even after I have disconnected my clients, the queue will still lose messages, about 1 every 5 seconds (I have no clue where the messages are going).

I have been searching for rogue connections or applications that are still connected and eating the queue but I cannot find anything.

There are no listed connections in the rabbitmq console

[image: Connections]

Below is the settings of the current queue in question.  I'm not sure if this is sufficient information or not.

[image: QueueSettings]

Here's how I'm queuing messages currently

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { /* Conneciton Info */};
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    var basicProps = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    basicProps.ContentType = "application/json";
    basicProps.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
    basicProps.SetPersistent(true);
    
    //declare queue
    channel.QueueDeclare("MyQueue", true, false, false, null);
    
    var message = SerializeMessageToJson(someMessage);
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    
    channel.BasicPublish("", "MyQueue", basicProps, body);
}
```

If someone can point me to some areas to troubleshoot or look into that would be fabulous.

Comment: Do you publish messages with per-message ttl set (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl)?

Comment: @zaq178miami no, i haven't.  I've updated my post to show the code i'm currently using to publish messages.  Is it suppose to be possible that the the messages can be consumed when there is no connections in the connections tab?

Comment: Hm... Do you have shovel plugin set up (or something like that)? Maybe you consumers actually run somewhere in background and periodically get messages? Also, there are rabbitmq official mailint list - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users, try to ask there.